# Do changes to request.url in Express middleware persist on to the next middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a middleware that rewrites the request.url. However in the next() middleware, the request.url is still the original unmodified url.

Example:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('Before Rewrite',req.url);
  if(/^\/v[1-9]/.test(req.originalUrl) ) {
    console.log('Rewritten');
    req.url = '/api' + req.originalUrl;
  }
  console.log('After Rewrite',req.url);
  next();
});
router.use('/api', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('Next', req.url);
  next();
});
```

With an example url of '/v3/foo' the following is output to console:

```
Before Rewrite /v3/foo
Rewritten
After Rewrite /api/v3/foo
Next /v3/foo
```

Any thoughts on why the request changes do not persist on to the next middleware?

Comment: Express trims `'/api'` from `req.url` when you use `app.use()`. From Express 4 docs "For example, the “mounting” feature of app.use() will rewrite req.url to strip the mount point." See: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.originalUrl      So your rewrite IS working. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the link from @kelz to the Express next() [code](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js#L189), I have a better understanding of how Express handles urls. It seems that req.url is writeable because Express removes the root of the url when matching. For example with an original url of '/foo/bar', if you have this:

router.use('/foo', someMiddleWare);

Then req.url within someMiddleWare will now be '/bar' i.e. with the matched root removed. This is why we have req.originalUrl (which is not writeable) to persist the unaltered url.

As my original approach to rewriting the url can't work, I opted for a simpler solution:

```
  router.all(/^\/v[1-9]/, function(req, res) { res.redirect('/api' + req.originalUrl); });
```

This way, after the redirect, the req.originalUrl is as it should be for my later middleware.

Comment: Thank you! I was having a similar problem and it looks like you can only rewrite url to automatically route to sub paths. For me I was at app.use('/foo/bar'.... and was trying to route to app.use('/foo/baz'... what I had to do is use a common parent path: app.use('/foo'.. and check if originalUrl = '/foo/bar'

Answer (score -1):

You are not sharing the same object in both functions. The moment you change the value of req in the middleware function the scope is bound only inside that function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Example:

```
function doAThing(a) {
  a = 5;
  return;
}
var n = 4;
doAThing(n);
console.log(n); // 4
```

Comment: I had a thought it would be to do with closures but assumed the request object was declared outside of the functions, i.e. within the router object or express object.

Comment: It is declared outside of the functions, but once you include it in a function parameter and change it inside the function, it only changes the scope inside that function. I think I see what you're thinking it would do, I'll show an example of how that would work.

Comment: Also, the second middleware is correctly fired because request.url now starts with '/api'

Comment: Ahh I see. Looks like my assumption about how express handles routes was wrong. From what I can see it looks like the express router has to trim a few parts of the path from the internal URL when it handles the route, and it then restores the route from different internal variables:

https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js#L189

It looks like a bit of a mess to be relying on this to override your routing - it might be a better idea to bind the original URLs to the same routing function rather than inline editing the req url to pop the /api/ routes.

Comment: @Kelz The above is correct, but only for primitive value types. The `req` object is a reference value type, and changing a property on it will change that value. So yes, the same object is shared between both functions. See: http://jsbin.com/lixokunuza/edit?js,console